# how to unlock passwd from the command "sudo passwd -l [user]"?

Tags: passwd

I locked the passwd for a user by using the command,

```
sudo passwd -l [user]
```

Then, how do I unlock the passwd for this user?

Comment: Usually, you can consult the man page for a command in these situations. In your case, you could have typed `man passwd`, then type `/unlock` and hit Enter in order to search for the word `unlock` in the man page. This leads directly to the option `-u`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo passwd -u [username]
```

from  `man passwd`:

> -u, --unlock Unlock the password of the named account. This option re-enables a password by changing the password back to its previous value (to the value before using the -l option).